# Variadic templated class - 0 length package constructor collision

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, sfinae

Given

```
template<class... Args>
struct foo {

    function<void(Args...)>     m_function;
    unique_ptr<tuple<Args...>>  m_args;

    foo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func, Args... args) :
        m_function{ func }, m_args{ new tuple<Args...>(args...) } {

        cout << "ctor 1" << endl;
    }

    // <some template wizardry here>
    foo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func) :
        m_function{ func } {

        cout << "ctor 2" << endl;
    }
};
```

I would like ctor2 to be instantiated only when `sizeof...(Args) != 0` (or else I get a collision..).

This right here seems to work (no collisions)

```
template<Args...>
foo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func) :
    m_function{ func } {

    cout << "ctor 2" << endl;
}
```

but I have no idea how/why or if it's reliable.

Also Id probably use something like

```
std::enable_if<sizeof...(Args) != 0, ???>
```

How can I resolve this using `std::enable_if` and what is going on in my 2nd code sample ?

Comment: This is completely sufficient: `template<class ... DummyArgs>
foo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func) `. The DummyArgs will always default to be sizeof 0, and the template will always be there. In the zero case, the compiler will prefer the non-template constructor.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb The template parameter can be unnamed to shorten it even more.

Comment: Alternatively you only want to have the second ctor called if sizeof Args... is greater than zero and you pass zero arguments. Therefore, you can write the constructors like this: `foo(std::false_type, const std::function<void(Args...)>& func, Args... args); foo(std::true_type, const std::function<void(Args...)>& func);`. And put a proxy constructor like `template<typename ... Args1> foo(const std::function<void(Args...)>& func, Args1... args):foo(std::bool_constant<sizeof...(Args) > 0 && sizeof...(Args1) == 0>(), func, args...) { }`.

Comment: by "I would like ctor2 to be instantiated only when sizeof...(Args) != 0", did you actually mean to say "I would like ctor2 to be instantiated only when sizeof...(Args) == 0"? ctor2 expects no args except for std::function right?

Comment: Yes (to your last question). I want to be able to store a function that takes argument without storing the actual arguments (if that makes sense). The `sizeof...(Args) == 0` case is already handled by the 1st constructor (although it lacks the `if` check to check if `sizeof...(Args) == 0` :p )

Comment: @PinkTurtle if your reason for using `unique_ptr` is to provide a _no arguments given_ state and you have c++17 at hand you might want to use `std::optional` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by Johannes Schaub - litb in a comment, you can simply add a variadic list of unused template parameters, just to transform your second contructor in a template one and give precedence (avoiding the collision) to the first one that isn't a template constructor.

So you can simply write

```
template <typename ...>
foo (std::function<void(Args...)> const & func)
    : m_function{ func }
 { std::cout << "ctor 2" << std::endl; }
```

But to satisfy your request

> I would like ctor2 to be instantiated only when `sizeof...(Args) != 0`

you can try with (less elegant but, maybe, more comprehensible)

```
template <bool B = (sizeof...(Args) > 0u),
          std::enable_if_t<B, bool> = true>
foo (std::function<void(Args...)> const & func)
    : m_function{ func }
 { std::cout << "ctor 2" << std::endl; }
```

Comment: What makes `bool B = (sizeof...(Args) > 0u), std::enable_if_t<B, bool> = true` work while `std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 0u), bool> = true` fails?

Comment: @Timo - SFINAE, over constructors and other methods, works when is based over test involving template parameter of the constructors/method itself; so `std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) > 0u), bool> = true` fails because `sizeof...(Args) > 0u` is a test based of template parameter of the class, not of the costructor. With `bool B = (sizeof...(Args) > 0u)` you create a template parameter, `B`, of the constructor that is involved in the following test of `std::enable_if`.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct foo {
    using Func = std::function<void(Args...)>;
    foo(const Func& func, Args... args)  { ... }

    struct none {};
    using A = typename std::conditional<sizeof...(Args) > 0, Func, none>::type;

    foo(const A& func) { ... };
```

Comment: But this would always result in two constructors and one might try to construct a `foo f(foo::none())`?

Comment: @Aconcagua you can make `none` private if you are concerned.